# SSL error curl/wget unknown protocol/wrong version number

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, curl, wget

I've been trying to use local hosted https urls in command line/cron jobs and i get those errors. curl output is similar. The same commands, when used in other servers works perfectly.

Default

```
[root@tejon ~]# wget -O /dev/null https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
--2013-05-27 10:33:38--  https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
Resolving www.domain.com... 173.45.38.60
Connecting to www.domain.com|173.45.38.60|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

TLSv1

```
[root@tejon ~]# wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 -O /dev/null https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
--2013-05-27 10:45:59--  https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
Resolving www.domain.com... 173.45.38.60
Connecting to www.domain.com|173.45.38.60|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

SSLv2

```
[root@tejon ~]# wget --secure-protocol=SSLv2 -O /dev/null https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
--2013-05-27 10:47:18--  https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
Resolving www.domain.com... 173.45.38.60
Connecting to www.domain.com|173.45.38.60|:443... connected.
```

and it blocks the input, but the file is not executed.

SSLv3

```
[root@tejon ~]# wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 -O /dev/null https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
--2013-05-27 10:43:23--  https://www.domain.com/cron/notification.php
Resolving www.domain.com... 173.45.38.60
Connecting to www.domain.com|173.45.38.60|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by the datacenter support.

Domains were added to /etc/hosts dont know how, once removed it worked.

Comment: Any idea why that was causing problems? I use the hosts file to resolve some regional databases I cycle through; it would be cool to know what the core problem was.